# If $\sum n^2 a_n^2<\infty$ then $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive integers, then prove/disprove:

If $\sum n^2 a_n^2<\infty$ then $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Do you know the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: The title and the question do not match. Please edit.

Comment: How AM GM will work  Erick Wong? can you explain?

Comment: Obviously the $a_n$ cannot be positive integers.

Comment: The statement is vacuously true since $\sum n^2a_n^2 =\infty$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the Cauchy—Schwarz Inequality in $l^\infty$.

> $(\sum |a_n||b_n||)^2 \leq (\sum a_n^2) \times (\sum b_n^2)$

Then we have

> $(\sum |a_n|)^2 \leq (\sum n^2 a_n^2) \times (\sum \frac{1}{n^2})$

Because

> $\sum n^2 a_n^2 < \infty$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$

So $\sum a_n < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Direct [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)

You can easily see that $ \sum n^2 a_n^2 > \sum a_n$.

By the comparison test, you can prove the the series $\sum a_n$ converge $\iff \sum n^2 a_n^2$  does.

Even thought it would never converge since $\lim a_n \ne 0$ (unless $a_n = 0$)

Comment: Take $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{\frac32}}$ : $\sum a_n$ converges, yet $\sum n^2 a_n^2=\sum \frac1n$ diverges...

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Given that $a_n$ positive

Comment: The counter example I gave is positive.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I'm sorry, I meant positive integers. your example is not Integers

Comment: I see, the OP indeed considers an integer sequence... I'm not quite sure why since he or she accepted goaxinge's answer which is the proof of the general case.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I believe he mistyped, otherwise it does not make sense what he is asking. And it would be a big of a coincidence you can solve it using C-S